# Interrupted apt upgrade broke udev and systemd

Tags: debian, package-management, systemd, udev

During an update of my Raspbian installation (Pi rev. B+) over SSH I lost connection. After a hard reboot (which may have happened during or after finishing the update) the udev kernel device manager fails on boot.

According to the journalctl (-xb), everything non-grey (white and red):

```
systemd-udev-trigger.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Failed to start udev Coldplug all Devices.
Unit systemd-udev-trigger.service entered failed state.

<snip>

systemd-udevd.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Failed to start udev Kernel Device Manager.
```

Those last two lines are repeated a couple of times.

```
Unit systemd-udevd.service entered failed state.
```

The result of udev failing becomes apparent later on:

```
random:nonblocking pool is initialized
Job dev-mmcblk0p1.device/start timed out.
Timed out waiting for device dev-mmcblk0p1.device.

<snip>

Dependency failed for /boot.

<snip>

Dependency failed for Local File Systems.

<snip>

Dependency Failed for File System Check on /dev/mmcblk0p1.

<snip>

Job dev-ttyAMA0.device/start timed out.
Timed out waiting for device dev-ttyAMA0.device.
```

The system is very broken at the moment. I checked the micro-SD for faults with fsck and so far without finding anything wrong.

How do I repair this mess?

Comment: There may be nothing you can do here.   For future reference, if something like this happens on the pi, don't yank the cord if the green ACT light is going, or at least not until you've given it a decent amount of time to stop.  The length of an update depends upon the size, but if it is blinking frequently, just let it go for 15 minutes or an hour; after that point if it's still going it's probably busy looped and you might as well pull the plug.  It is unlikely to be actively destroying data, so trying to stop it ASAP is prone to do more harm than good.

Comment: @goldilocks In hindsight I shouldn't have pulled the plug, but I thought the SSH server had simply died on me and would've aborted the update. Not exactly sure what I was thinking really. But I'm hoping there's some method of repair available to get it back up and running. We have the technology.